# Finding an example for sequence of functions

Tags: integration

Given any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, how do I find a sequence of non-negative functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ does not converge for any point $x\in[a,b]$ but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^b_af_n(x)\ dx=0.$$

Can someone give me some hint as to how to start? I've been scratching my head for hours and couldn't come up with any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming $a=0,b=1$, but obviously this generalizes. For all $k,n\in\mathbb N$, let $$g_{n,k}(x)=\begin{cases}1&k<nx<k+1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Consider the sequence $$g_{1,0}, g_{2,0},g_{2,1},g_{3,0},g_{3,1},g_{3,2},g_{4,0},\ldots$$Can you show that this satisfies the condition you are looking for?

Comment: Oh I'm stupid, thanks very much!